# Returning a prezipped static content instead of zipping it on the fly

Tags: php, database, json, gzip

I have a lot of static JSON text content indexed in a database. Some of this content is greater than 20K. Web pages request this content via Ajax and a call to a PHP file to fetch the data in the database.

Of course, one can gzip the returned content on the fly, but I was wondering whether I could fetch pre-gzipped content and return it directly from PHP. In other words, I could pre-gzip entries and store them in the database itself, rather than the full text.

Is this possible? If yes, how do I indicate in PHP that the returned content is gzipped binary? I use `echo` for plain text, but which command should I use for binary data? I am no expert at PHP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would also echo the gzipped data. echo is simply a "write these bytes to the output buffer". You can echo images if you want. The interesting thing is, what you tell the browser to do with the data. This is where the HTTP response headers come in. You need to send a Content-Encoding header. But you need to make sure, that the client is able to understand gzip, for this to work at all. You should also know, that there are two different compression algorithms in use: DEFLATE and GZIP.

```
<?php
$data = fetchGzippedDataFromDatabase();
if (stripos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"], 'gzip') !== false) {
  header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
  echo $data;
} else {
  // client does not accept gzipped data
  echo gzdecode($data);
  // or gzinflate() or gzuncompress() 
  // depending on what you used to compress in the first place
}
```

You might want to consider using a reverse proxy (nginx, varnish, squid, …) and have them handle output compression.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You would need to modify the HTTP headers (Content-type, Content-Length, Transfer-Encoding), via the [header](http://php.net/header) function.

But beware, you would need to parse the accepted transfer encodings proposed by the client (deflate, gzip, etc) and deal with *all* of them. If you send deflate to a gzip client, or vice versa, it won't work as expected.

Also, remember there is a difference between gzip transfer encoding and gzip file format. You probably need to find a library that implements this in php or do the dirty work your self.

In either way, Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the content is static, I suggest you circument the "fetch from db" step entirely and try a caching mechanism that supports gzip-encoding the response or caching the gzipped version.

[Here is a link](http://webdirect.no/linux/apache-caching-with-gzip-enabled/) to somebody who did that for Apache. Another solution would be [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

Answer (score 2):

**Apache Web Server Alternative**

First, if you are using [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) the you might want to enable and configure [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html). It will handle content compression before sending it to the client.

**PHP Alternative #1**

If not, then you may be able to use [ob_gzhandler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) (PHP 4 >= 4.0.4, PHP 5) to activate gzip output buffer.

```
if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) ob_start();
echo $json;
```

**PHP Alternative #2**

Another possibility (not tested) could be caching the contents on disk rather than putting the gzip contents into the database if these are more used in uncompressed format. Using [gzencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php).

```
$json = array('id' => $id, 'content' => $content);
$file = '/tmp/' . $json['id'] . '.json';
if(!file_exists($file)) {
  $gzip = gzencode($json['content']);
  file_put_contents($file, $gzip);
} else {
  $gzip = file_get_contents($file);
}
header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($gzip));
echo $gzip;
```

This way may work for outputting only gzipped content and it may not work as is in all browsers.

**PHP Alternative #2.5**

Output gzipped content from disk cache when browsers accepts it only.

```
$json = array('id' => $id, 'content' => $content);
if( strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"],'gzip') !== false ) {
  $file = '/tmp/' . $json['id'] . '.json';
  if(!file_exists($file)) {
    $gzip = gzencode($json['content']);
    file_put_contents($file, $gzip);
  } else {
    $gzip = file_get_contents($file);
  }
  header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
  header('Content-Length: '.strlen($gzip));
  echo $gzip;
} else {
  echo $json['content'];
}
```